# Piping a Python script output continuosly to another program

Tags: python, unix, pipe

I want to output some data from a Python script continuously to another program. As an example I will use `cat`, this is what currently happens:

If my `test1.py` script is like this:

```
print("Hello!")
```

when I run `./test1.py | cat` the output is `Hello!`, it works because the script terminates immediately after execution.

The problem occurs when I have a script that writes continuously and never terminates like `test2.py`:

```
import time

a = 0
while True:
  a += 1
  print(a)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Then `./test2.py | cat` just hangs there because the script is not terminating.

I would like to send one number every second to `cat` and display it in real time, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `flush=True` in your print, your output is getting buffered, there is a nice artice [Unix buffering delays output to stdout, ruins your day](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering) that explains what is going on:

```
import time

a = 0
while True:
  a += 1
  print(a, flush=True)
  time.sleep(1)
```

If you are using python2 add `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: This fixed my problem, I will mark this one as the correct answer because it does not require to directly use `sys.stdout`, it is also nice to know about the new Python3 features.

Comment: @dan_s, no worries, I added a link to an article that gives a nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush to the stdout after printing. So your code will look like this:

```
import sys
import time

a = 0
while True:
    a += 1
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now running `python script.py | cat` will print a.

Answer (score 0):

./test2.py | tail -f

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>
> ```
>       output  appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent
> ```